# Visual Studio Code: pass wildcard characters as argument in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Version: 1.27.1

OS: macOS 10.13.6

It seems that wildcard expansion is not supprted in launch.json of VSCode, e.g. if I pass src/main/*.txt as one of the arguments to an executable, no txt files could be found in the target directory. My workaround for now is to specify explicitly the filename in the config.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to get the wildcard * expanded in launch.json as in the config tasks.json?

Answer (score 2):

For those who might have the same question, I've got an answer from a dev member:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58698

Basically VS Code doesn't support wildcard by itself in launch.json. You are lucky if the debugger extension can do it directly or provide the console property to tweak in the config.